# Haskell as a scripting language

Tags: haskell, plugins, hint

**Are there any redistributable<sup>1</sup> solutions<sup>2</sup> to loading Haskell scripts<sup>3</sup> from a Haskell program?**

<sup>1</sup> Statically linked; not need the end user to install ghc or have anything special on their PATH.

<sup>2</sup> Ie a library plus some setup on my end.

<sup>3</sup> That are written in Haskell, and have access to some set of symbols exported from the program doing the loading. This is the important one. I've been able to load and run code snippets with hint, but I haven't been able to get them to see any symbols in my program, which is how scripting systems normally work.

Comment: The "symbols in your program" don't _exist_ at runtime, except in interpreted mode.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Is there no way to get at them?

Comment: @Dan Look at the code ghc generates. It's very much not Haskell-y at all.

Comment: @Cubic Not necessarily get at them directly, but possibly though some kind of stub mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Idea #1: If you want the code to have access to certain functions, you could just pass those functions in as arguments. (May not work well if there's a huge number of them though.)

Idea #2: FFI allows you to export symbols to C, so it should be possible to import those back into Haskell on the other side. Probably ugly though.